# Casting pflags.Flag.Value as Arbitrary Types

Tags: go, command-line-interface, cobra, pflag-go

I am using `github.com/spf13/cobra` to parse command-line flags and just about everything I'm doing is working well, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get a specifically typed value out of a `*cobra.Command` at runtime.

My command definition looks like this in `cmd/generate.go`:

```golang
var (
    generateCommand = &cobra.Command{
        // ...
    }

    generateTokenCommand = &cobra.Command{
        // ...
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
           // command body here
        }
    }

)

func init() {
    generateCommand.AddCommand(generateTokenCommand)

    // setup generate token flags
    flags := generateTokenCommand.Flags()
    flags.Uint64P("user-id", "i", 1, "User ID")
    flags.BoolP("is-admin", "a", "Is admin.")
    // other flags.StringP, but those are easy
}
```

> NOTE: I know that there are APIs for binding these to static variables, I'm trying to avoid doing that if at all possible to keep things contained within Cobra.

Inside `generateTokenCommand.Run`, e.g. my entry point, I'm having trouble getting non-string values out of `cobra.Command`.

When I need to get a string value, I can simply:

```golang
var email string = cmd.Flag("email").Value.String()
```

[`pflags.Flag`](https://github.com/spf13/pflag/blob/v1.0.5/flag.go#L171) has a field named `Value`, which is of type [`pflags.Value`](https://github.com/spf13/pflag/blob/v1.0.5/flag.go#L187), which looks like this:

```golang
// Value is the interface to the dynamic value stored in a flag.
// (The default value is represented as a string.)
type Value interface {
    String() string
    Set(string) error
    Type() string
}
```

If I drop into a debugger and grab the value like so:

```golang
userIdValue := cmd.Flag("user-id").Value
```

I see that the runtime type of this is [`*github.com/spf13/pflag.uint64Value`](https://github.com/spf13/pflag/blob/v1.0.5/uint64.go), but since this is a private type, I don't seem to be able to cast the value:

```golang
// does not compile
cmd.Flag("user-id").Value.(uint64)
```

How can I cast or use another method to resolve this `Value` as a `uint64`?

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the answer after diving deeper, there is a method on `pflags.FlagSet` called [`GetUint64`](https://github.com/spf13/pflag/blob/v1.0.5/uint64.go#L34):

```golang
// GetUint64 return the uint64 value of a flag with the given name
func (f *FlagSet) GetUint64(name string) (uint64, error) {
    val, err := f.getFlagType(name, "uint64", uint64Conv)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return val.(uint64), nil
}
```

I think my issue has been getting used to the documentation and the way that Golang source code is organized, but this does work:

```golang
uid, err := cmd.Flags().GetUint64("user-id")
```